# Sqlsrv: Could not find the driver

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, xampp, sqlsrv

I'm using XAMPP with PHP v8.2 on my localhost (Windows 10) and I have downloaded the related DLLs from [Windows 8.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/v5.11.0) and pasted the `ts` (thread safe) versions to **`xampp/php/ext`** directory:

```
php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
php_sqlsrv.dll
```

And also call them inside `php.ini` like this:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv
extension=php_sqlsrv
```

But I get this error:

**could not find driver**

According to this line of code:

```
 $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DBNAME;TrustServerCertificate=true", "USER", "PASSWORD");
```

And `phpinfo()` is not showing `sqlsrv` some how!

I also tried copying and pasting the `nts` versions but still not working!

So what's going wrong here?

Is there any other step that I need to do in order to define this `sqlsrv` driver properly inside Xampp with PHP v8.2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have the chance to verify the exact syntax and startup errors?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing the old and the new syntax:

```
; Note : The syntax used in previous PHP versions ('extension=<ext>.so' and
; 'extension='php_<ext>.dll') is supported for legacy reasons and may be
; deprecated in a future PHP major version. So, when it is possible, please
; move to the new ('extension=<ext>) syntax.
```

So it's either this (preferred):

```
extension=pdo_sqlsrv
extension=sqlsrv
```

... or this:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
```

To have invalid extension files reported, you can enable the [`display_startup_errors` INI directive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors) (otherwise, just check the appropriate log files).

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_foo'
> (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/php_foo (/usr/lib/php/20210902/php_foo:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory),
> /usr/lib/php/20210902/php_foo.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/php_foo.so:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown
> on line 0